# How do I replace multiple letters in an array or string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I've tried googling a bit but haven't had much success.
What I'm trying to do is change every letter in a string to something else. For example 
"this is a string"
would turn to something like 
"&@/- 52 - .'49-!"

So far I've got my string/phrase as

```
    let phrase = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

then afterwards

```
    phrase = phrase.map(phrase => {
    return phrase.replace('a', '-');
    return phrase.replace('b', '!');
    return phrase.replace('c', ',');
    return phrase.replace('d', ';'); 
    return phrase.replace('e', ',');
    return phrase.replace('f', '(');
```

.. all the way to Z, then

```
    });
    console.log(phrase);
```

When I run it, I get this output

```
    [ '-', 'b', 'c' ]
```

but it should be this

```
    [ '-', '!', ',' ]
```

which means it's only 'translating' the first letter and skipping the rest,whereas I need it to translate the entire string.

I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use an object organized by `replace: replaceWith` instead:

```js
const replacements = {
  a: '-',
  b: '!',
  c: ',',
  d: ';',
  e: ',',
  f: '('
};
const input = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const output = input.map(inputPhrase => replacements[inputPhrase]);
console.log(output);
```

If the phrases to be replaced can contain characters that can't be bare keys, enclose them in strings:

```js
const replacements = {
  a: '-',
  b: '!',
  c: ',',
  d: ';',
  e: ',',
  f: '(',
  '###': 'foo'
};
const input = ['a', 'b', 'c', '###'];
const output = input.map(inputPhrase => replacements[inputPhrase]);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` quits from the function - either reassign `phrase` each time:

```js
let phrase = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

phrase = phrase.map(phrase => {
  phrase = phrase.replace('a', '-');
  phrase = phrase.replace('b', '!');
  phrase = phrase.replace('c', ',');
  phrase = phrase.replace('d', ';');
  phrase = phrase.replace('e', ',');
  return phrase.replace('f', '(');
});

console.log(phrase);
```

Or use an object (use `toLowerCase` to avoid case sensitivity - just remove it if you want different characters for `a` and `A`):

```js
let phrase = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const replace = {
  "a": "-",
  "b": "!",
  "c": ",",
  "d": ";",
  "e": ",",
  "f": "("
};

phrase = phrase.map(phrase => replace[phrase.toLowerCase()]);

console.log(phrase);
```